# Binding для элемента Picker в Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

Добрый день. Подскажите где поколдовать что бы заработал binding для контрола Picker?
Вот XAML:

```
<Picker ItemsSource="{Binding cats}" />
```

Вот код:

```
public List<String> cats => new List<string> 
{ 
"Cat Mau", "Cat Vasa" 
};
```

Итого пустой список. Везде в примерах всё так-же, все счастливы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `this.BindingContext`, как в примере : [Bindable Picker Control](https://blog.xamarin.com/new-bindable-picker-control-for-xamarin-forms/)

**C#:**

```
public class RegistrationPageViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ....

    List<string> countries = new List<string>
    {
        "Afghanistan",
        "Albania",
        "Algeria",
        "Andorra",
        "Angola",
        ...
    };
    public List<string> Countries => countries;

    ...
}

public partial class RegistrationPage : ContentPage
{
    RegistrationPageViewModel vm;

    public RegistrationPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.BindingContext = vm = new RegistrationPageViewModel();
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<Picker ItemsSource="{Binding Countries}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Во-первых, рекомендую использовать ObservableCollection вместо List. 
Во-вторых, используй вот эту штуку:
NuGet: https://www.nuget.org/packages/JPC.BindablePicker/ 
GitHub: https://github.com/joacar/BindablePicker

```
public ObservableCollection<string> Cats { get; set;}

public NameYourClass()
{
   Cats = new ObservableCollection {"Cat1", "Cat2"};
}
```

Ну и XAML код будет аналогичный, только используешь не базовый Picker, а BindablePicker:

```
<bindablePicker:BindablePicker ItemsSource={Binding Cats} />
```

И не по теме: Не забывай про хороший тон в C# - публичные поля с большой буквы.